# How to create app for iphone which gets data from blog site?

Tags: blogs

I want to create an app which gets data from a blog site and display it in custom sized table view. where each cell displays few lines of article and who wrote it which when clicked will display full article and also take comments from reader. can anyone guide me to any such tutorial or tell me how can i do it? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you will probably want to use the rss feed for that site, instead of the HTML. This tutorial should be helpful...
http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/